# R: Single Cell tracking X and Y coordinates (Position) changes during time course

Tags: r, time, coordinates

I have two dataframes (a 1-minute time point and a 26-minute time point).

I have `PosX` and `PosY` (X and Y positions in the image at that particular time point for all cells detected) and my readout of interest

Over time the cells migrate slightly. I have calculated the shift in X and Y (`delta_x` and `delta_y`) using:

```
delta_x <-  median_x_0nM_26min - median_x_0nM_1min 
delta_y <-  median_y_0nM_26min - median_y_0nM_1min
```

I have then added this change to my starting X and Y values

```
Xmax <- DF_1min$PosX + delta_x
Xmin <- DF_1min$PosX - delta_x
Ymax <- DF_1min$PosY + delta_Y
Ymin <- DF_1min$PosY - delta_Y

DF_1min <- cbind(DF_1min, Xmax, Xmin, Ymax, Ymin)
```

How do I find which cells in `DF_26min` correspond to the cells in `DF_1min` by allowing `PosX` to fall within the `Xmax` and `Xmin` range of cells in DF_1min and PosY to fall within the Ymax and Ymin range?

Perhaps an even better solution might be a next-nearest neighbor solution but this sounds like it might be beyond the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For finding the ***nearest*** in `DF_1min`, for every cell position in `DF_26min`:

  *distance* function based on *euclidean* distance, from a point `x` to a collection/ dataframe `df`:

  ```
  distance <- function(x, df = DF_1min) {
  apply( df[,c('PosX','PosY')], 1, function(y) {diff <- (y - x); sqrt(sum(diff^2))} )
                                        }

  # calculating nearest/ min distance for every cell position in DF_26min
  nearest <- apply( DF_26min, 1, function(y) which.min(x = distance(y)) )
  ```

  you can also check the `dist` function for easy implementation of other distance measures foreg. "manhattan", "canberra", "binary" or "minkowski" etc.

  ```
  # Nearest indices from DF_1min and corresponding X, Y positions
  DF_26min['Nearest'] <- nearest
  DF_26min[,c('Nearest_Pos_X', 'Nearest_Pos_Y')] <- DF_1min[nearest,c('PosX', 'PosY')]
  ```
- For checking at *26 min*, if `PosX` & `PosY` are ***independently*** and ***point-wise*** in range to its `nearest` point, you can do this to get logic vectors of equal length:

  ```
  DF_26min[,'X_Inrange'] <- ((DF_26min$PosX >= DF_1min[nearest,'Xmin']) & (DF_26min$PosX <= DF_1min[nearest,'Xmax']))
  DF_26min[,'Y_Inrange'] <- ((DF_26min$PosY >= DF_1min[nearest,'Ymin']) & (DF_26min$PosY <= DF_1min[nearest,'Ymax']))
  DF_26min[,'PXY_Inrange'] <- (rowSums(DF_26min[,c('X_Inrange','Y_Inrange')]) == 2)
  ```
- For finding the **nearest among the in range** cells/ positions:`NIR`

  ```
  Nearest_IR <- function(x, df = DF_1min) {

       n <- nrow(df)
       X_Inrange <- ((rep(x[1],n) >= DF_1min[,'Xmin']) & (rep(x[1],n) <= DF_1min[,'Xmax']))
       Y_Inrange <- ((rep(x[2],n) >= DF_1min[,'Ymin']) & (rep(x[2],n) <= DF_1min[,'Ymax'])) 
       XY_Inrange <- (rowSums(cbind(X_Inrange,Y_Inrange)) == 2)  
       distance <- apply( df[,c('PosX','PosY')] , 1 , function(y) {diff <- (y - x) ; sqrt(sum(diff^2))} )

       df_temp <- cbind(ID = seq.int(n), df, XY_Inrange, distance)

       if (sum(df_temp$XY_Inrange == TRUE) == 0 ){
       return (NA)   
       } else {
       NIR <- df_temp$ID[df_temp$distance == min(df_temp$distance[df_temp$XY_Inrange == TRUE])]
       return (NIR)  }  
                                            }

  DF_26min[,'Nearest_IR'] <- apply( DF_26min, 1, Nearest_IR )

  DF_26min[,c(1:3,8,9)]
  # PosX  PosY    Nearest PXY_Inrange Nearest_IR
  # 1.0   0.0     5           FALSE   NA
  # 2.0   1.0     2           TRUE    2
  # 1.5   2.0     3           TRUE    3
  # 2.2   0.5     4           FALSE   5
  ```

  **Data:**

  ```
  DF_26min = data.frame(PosX = c(1,2,1.5,2.2) , PosY = c(0,1,2,0.5))
  DF_1min <- data.frame(PosX = c(4.2,2.1,1.8,2.1,2.05) , PosY = c(0.2,1.1,2.15,0.6,0.5))
  DF_1min['Xmin'] <- DF_1min['PosX']*0.8
  DF_1min['Xmax'] <- DF_1min['PosX']*1.1
  DF_1min['Ymin'] <- DF_1min['PosY']*0.9
  DF_1min['Ymax'] <- DF_1min['PosY']*1.2
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you know how to alter the above so that I could cross-reference the two tables so I could match position. The problem I have is that not all cells show up in the 26 min timepoint vesus the 1min time point. That is, some cells end up either dyeing or losing the stain to identify them.

For example I have 163 cells in DF_1min and 135 for DF_26min. Cells were not counted in order either, so I need to be able to test the PosX and PosY for 26mins against the range (Xmin and Xmax, Ymin and Ymax) of all of the cells at 1min.

Comment: In this case a cell at 26 min might fall in range for multiple cells at 1 min. Do you want to return a vector representing which all points in DF_1min are in range for every point in DF_26 separately ?

Comment: Yes please however I guess it would better to use a nearest cell correction. That is despite two cells in DF_26min matching 1 for DF_1min, one of those cells would be closer than the other? 

Thanks so much for your help with this. I am presenting at a conference next week and will be sure to mention this work as a future direction.

Comment: Nice. Glad to help. On thing, nearest doesn't necessarily means that it will be in range, for eg. it might be outside the range and still be nearest. do you want both the conditions satisfied or nearest will do?

Comment: I modified the code to find nearest and then check if in its range of it. Note that there might be other not so near points but can have a point in its range.

Comment: @MarkGraham . I hope you got your issue resolved. Do upvote/ accept the answer to let others know, if this answer solved your issue.

Comment: Dear Mankind_008, thanks ever so much for your help. I did upvote for some reason (I have less than 15 rep score) it can't be publically displayed? I hope that your coding is going well